# problem with missing values for calculating the median

Tags: r, median

I'm having problem with managing with NAs to calculate median by using multiple matrix.

This is an example of the code and data I'm working on:

```
#Data example

m1 = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)  
m2 = matrix(c(NA, 5, 7, 9),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
m3 = matrix(c(NA, 8, 10, 14),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
 
Median calculation

apply(abind::abind(m1, m2, m3, along = 3), 1:2, median)
         [,1] [,2]
     [1,] NA    5
     [2,]  7    9
```

As expected the the function doesn't return a value for cells which contains NAs.

The problem is that if I replace NAs with 0 I'll get an output like this:

#Data example

```
m1 = matrix(c(2, 4, 3, 1),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)  
m2 = matrix(c(0, 5, 7, 9),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
m3 = matrix(c(0, 8, 10, 14),nrow=2, ncol=2, byrow = TRUE)
 
Median calculation

apply(abind::abind(m1, m2, m3, along = 3), 1:2, median)
         [,1] [,2]
     [1,]  0    5
     [2,]  7    9
```

I'm trying instead to get an output where cells which reports NAs are just skipped so that only values are take into consideration. As in the example, if I have cells with `NA, NA, 2` I would expect to get `2` as result while (out of the example) for cells with `NA,2,5` I would expect `3.5` as result.

```
         [,1] [,2]
     [1,]  2    5
     [2,]  7    9
```

Do you have an idea of how I could get this results? Any suggestion would be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the argument `na.rm=TRUE` inside `apply`

```
apply(abind::abind(m1, m2, m3, along = 3), 1:2, median, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Output:

```
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    2    5
[2,]    7    9
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you should drop de NA's first? Try adding na.rm = TRUE